# set username and password to soap wsdl request in soap ui app

Tags: soap

I have a soap wsdl webservice and I must use user name and password for my requset but I dont know where?
Actually the provider said that I must add this value as a property to my request,,

But now when I add these property to my request from the default property panel of soap ui it doesnt work correctly,,
below is my source code that I use in soap ui request panel

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:bpm="http://test.co/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <dpm:getTransactionById>
         <bpm:referenceId>fgdfgdgfdfgdfgd</bpm:referenceId>
      </dpm:getTransactionById>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

is there a way for adding some parameter in header block of xml soap requset?
thanks a bunch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 solution for you to solve your problem,,

First solution:
you can add username and password in your soap xml request not only for password but also for time stamp(but it depend on your service provider) but in most cases this senario is true,so then after call the api another time
below is the sample code.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:bpm="http://xxxxxxx.co/" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://xxxxxx.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://xxxxx.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-xxxxx">
            <wsu:Created>2023-01-04T08:04:26.709Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2023-01-04T08:05:26.709Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <wsse:Username>xxxxxxxxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://xxxxxx.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxxx</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://xxxxxxx.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xxxx</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2023-01-04T08:02:55.404Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <dpm:getTransactionById>
         <bpm:referenceId>fgdfgdgfdfgdfgd</bpm:referenceId>
      </dpm:getTransactionById>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

you can see add user name password and time stamp to our request.

in second solution you can click right in soap ui app requset and choose
add wss username token and ws time stamp and set your configuration,

I hope the solution work for for you,,,
best regard..

Comment: I used your solution and it works for me